# Overriding Previous Background in CSS

Tags: html, css

So I'm having a problem and I think it may be that my understanding of css rules is lacking.  Hopefully you guys can help me out!

```
span.medback {
background-color: FFFFCC; 
}
span.hiback {
background-color: FF3333;
}
span.item1 {
display: block;
background-color:#DCF0F7;
width: 75px;
height: 58px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
float: left;
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
}
span.item2 {
display: block;
background-color:#DCF0F7;
width: 70px;
height: 58px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
float: left;
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
}
span.item3 {
display: block;
background-color:#DCF0F7;
width: 90px;
height: 58px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
float: left;
overflow: auto;
padding: 5px;
}
span.item4 {
display: block;
background-color:#DCF0F7;
width: 170px;
height:48px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
float: left;
overflow: auto;
padding: 10px;
}
span.item5 {
display: block;
background-color: #DCF0F7;
width: 80px;
height:58px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
float:left;
padding: 5px;
}
span.item6 {
display: block;
background-color: #DCF0F7;
width: 30px;
height: 58px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
float:left;
padding: 5px;
}

span.item6 a img {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
}
span.item1 a img {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
}

span.item7 {
display: block;
background-color: #DCF0F7;
width: 30px;
height: 58px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
float:left;
padding: 5px;
}
```

Pardon the extremely long CSS line- its necessary to get an idea of my problem

```
<ul id="sortable" class="mainlist"><li class="listwrap" id="arrange_69"><span class="item1 "><a class="checkmarked" href=""><img src="" title="check" alt="check" /></a></span>
<span class="item2 ">&#x25B2; | &#x25BC;</span>
<span class="item3 ">monkey</span>
<span class="item4 "></span>
<span class="item5 "></span>
<span class="item6 "><a class="edit" href=""><img title="edit" alt="edit" src="" /></a></span>
<span class="item7 "><a class="confirm" href=""><img title="Delete" alt="Delete"src="" /></a></span></li>
<li class="listwrap" id="arrange_72"><span class="item1 hiback"><a class="checkmarked" href=""><img src="" title="check" alt="check" /></a></span>
<span class="item2 hiback">&#x25B2; | &#x25BC;</span>
<span class="item3 hiback">new</span>
<span class="item4 hiback"></span>
<span class="item5 hiback">Mar 25th 2014 12:30 PM</span>
<span class="item6 hiback"><a class="edit" href=""><img title="edit" alt="edit" src="" /></a></span>
<span class="item7 hiback"><a class="confirm" href=""><img title="Delete" alt="Delete"src="" /></a></span></li></ul>
```

My question is why doesn't the hiback class in the second li override the background color of the other elements? Is there a way that I can get that functionality?  (rewriting the whole thing is an option if its designed poorly)  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your first step in debugging should have been to validate your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that these should have `#` signs for the colors:

```
span.medback {
    background-color: #FFFFCC; 
}

span.hiback {
    background-color: #FF3333;
}
```

Second, you should move the definition of these after the definition of the item classes.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ybJGw/

Comment: Thanks!  So in css rules, its not which one gets named last in the html, its which one gets defined last in the css? edit- switched first to last(my brain is going to explode)

Comment: @Jimbo the order of declarations is also a rule to determine which one overrides the other (beside other rules), that's some kind of basic CSS knowledge.

Comment: No, look at the links from Quentin's answer.  If two selectors are equally specific, it's the one that is defined last in the css that wins.  That's why moving .medback and .hiback after the .item definitions allows .hiback to be picked up.

Answer (score 2):

Because:

- Your rules for the hiback class are invalid, you are missing a `#` from the colour code
- The selectors are equally [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity)
- When selectors are equally specific, [the *last* one gets applied last](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order) (overriding the earlier ones)